# Capture single row in a datagridview

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a .NET windows app.

I have a `DataGridView` which has a few rows in it. I had added a column containing buttons to allow the user to edit a row. This pops up a new form/dialog - my edit form.

```
// Add a CellClick handler to handle clicks in the button column.
dgv.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellClick);
```

The code which fires this is:

```
private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{    
    if (e.ColumnIndex == buttonCell)
    {
        // Get the id number
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);


        EditForm edit = new EditForm(number);
        edit.ShowDialog();                   
    }
}
```

**Problem**

My edit form displays (correctly). I make my changes, and close the form. It then loads again! It does this for the same number of rows in my Grid. Ie. It fires the code above once for each row in the DataGrid.

How can I prevent this? Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make sure you're not registering the `CellClick` event more than once.

i.e., that you're not calling this code more than once (like each time you add a row to your DGV):

```
dgv.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellClick);
```

Comment: Oh my god, how did I miss this?! Thank you for your help. Man, I feel so stupid.

Answer (score 0):

> To determine when the cell contents are clicked, handle the CellContentClick event.

Trying using dgv.CellContentClick instead and see if that fixes the issue. Check the docs for the [datagridview.cellclick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx)